# Problems in formalizing these sentences

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

This is the first sentence that I have to formalize:

> "Every student likes at least one type of cake"

Let:

- $S(x)$ stands for '*x* is a student'
- $C(x)$ stands for '*x* is a type of cake'
- $L(x,y)$ stands for '*x* likes *y*'

My formalisation is:

$\forall x (S(x)\rightarrow \exists y (C(y) \wedge L(x,y)))$

Is it correct? 
Or should I write:

$\forall x \exists y (S(x)\wedge C(y) \rightarrow L(x,y))$ ?

The second sentence is:

> "There is a type of cake such that every student likes it"

Is the following formalisation correct?

$\exists x (C(x) \wedge \forall y (S(y) \rightarrow L(y,x)))$

Many thanks for the help

Comment: Introducing multiple meanings of $x$ does not seem like the best idea here.

Comment: @induktio thanks for your reply but I don't understand what do you mean by 'introducing multiple meanings of x'...

Comment: Maybe it's not a big deal since $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ can be clearly distinguished, but I think something like $C(y)$ would be easier to deal with. Just a thought :)

Comment: @Gloria: In one statement $x$ refers to a student in the last statement it refers to a cake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

- formalization $\forall x (S(x)\rightarrow \exists y (C(y) \wedge L(x,y)))$ is correct;
- formalization $\forall x \exists y (S(x)\wedge C(y) \rightarrow L(x,y))$ is *not* correct, suppose that there is an object $y_0$ which is not a cake (perhaps a student), then setting $y = y_0$ would make the formula true even if all students dislike all cakes;
- formalization $\exists x (C(x) \wedge \forall y (S(y) \rightarrow L(y,x)))$ is correct.

To give you some intuition:

- You could think of *unary* predicates as sets, in particular

$$\forall x \in S\ (\Phi)\quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad\forall x \big(S(x) \to \Phi\big)$$
$$\exists x \in S\ (\Phi)\quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad\exists x \big(S(x) \land \Phi\big)$$

- Your first formula is $\forall x \in S\ \Big( \exists y \in C\ \big(L(x,y)\big)\Big)$.
- Your second formula can be rewritten as
  \begin{align}
  &\forall x \exists y \big(S(x)\wedge C(y) \rightarrow L(x,y)\big)\\
  &\forall x \exists y \Big(S(x)\to \big(C(y) \to L(x,y)\big)\Big)\\
  &\forall x \Big(S(x)\to \exists y \big(C(y) \to L(x,y)\big)\Big)\\
  &\forall x \in S\ \exists y \Big(C(y)\land\big(C(y) \to L(x,y)\big) \lor \neg C(y)\land\big(C(y) \to L(x,y)\big)\Big)\\
  &\forall x \in S\ \exists y \Big(C(y)\land L(x,y) \lor \neg C(y)\Big)\\
  &\forall x \in S\ \Big(\exists y \big(C(y)\land L(x,y)\big) \lor \exists y \big(\neg C(y)\big)\Big)\\
  &\forall x \in S\ \Big(\exists y \in C\ \big(L(x,y)\big) \lor \exists y \in \overline{C}\Big)\\
  \end{align}
  which could be read as "for every student there is a cake that he likes or something which is not a cake".
- Your third formula is $\exists x \in C\ \Big(\forall y \in S\ \big(L(y,x)\big)\Big)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Damn dude--I dig that. Nice.

Comment: This answer really helps me a lot...Thanks!